# Swift & Spritekit: Creation of a slope

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to create a slope in a 2D game. This slope should have a degree X. When now a ball is rolling "over" this slope. The effect of this slope should change then the behaviour of the ball so rolling back, forward or where else the slope degree is initialized. I thought that I can achieve this with a SKSpritenode with a physical body and when the ball is rolling over ("colliding") the effect should be affected to the ball, but I was no able to achieve this.

How can I achieve this?

Best regards,

chris

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for the slope to have a physics effect on the ball as it travels up or down the slope.

Take a look at the sample project below (the project is in landscape mode and with show physics set to YES).

```
#import "GameScene.h"

typedef NS_OPTIONS(uint32_t, Level1PhysicsCategory) {
    CategoryBall  = 1 << 0,
    CategoryFloor0  = 1 << 1,
};

@implementation GameScene {
    SKSpriteNode *ballNode;
}

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor whiteColor];

    // create slope floor
    SKSpriteNode *myNode0 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor clearColor] size:CGSizeMake(200, 100)];
    myNode0.position = CGPointMake(500,300);
    myNode0.zPosition = 100;
    CGMutablePathRef trianglePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(trianglePath, nil, -myNode0.size.width/2, myNode0.size.height/2);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(trianglePath, nil, myNode0.size.width/2, -myNode0.size.height/2);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(trianglePath, nil, -myNode0.size.width/2, -myNode0.size.height/2);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(trianglePath, nil, -myNode0.size.width/2, myNode0.size.height/2);
    myNode0.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:trianglePath];
    myNode0.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    myNode0.physicsBody.restitution = 0;
    myNode0.physicsBody.friction = 0.0;
    myNode0.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CategoryFloor0;
    myNode0.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = CategoryBall;
    CGPathRelease(trianglePath);
    [self addChild:myNode0];

    // create top floor
    SKSpriteNode *myNode1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor clearColor] size:CGSizeMake(300, 5)];
    myNode1.position = CGPointMake(250,348);
    myNode1.zPosition = 100;
    myNode1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(300, 5)];
    myNode1.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    myNode1.physicsBody.restitution = 0;
    myNode1.physicsBody.friction = 0.0;
    myNode1.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CategoryFloor0;
    myNode1.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = CategoryBall;
    [self addChild:myNode1];

    // create bottom floor
    SKSpriteNode *myNode2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor clearColor] size:CGSizeMake(300, 5)];
    myNode2.position = CGPointMake(750,248);
    myNode2.zPosition = 100;
    myNode2.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(300, 5)];
    myNode2.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    myNode2.physicsBody.restitution = 0;
    myNode2.physicsBody.friction = 0.0;
    myNode2.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CategoryFloor0;
    myNode2.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = CategoryBall;
    [self addChild:myNode2];

    // create ball
    ballNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor clearColor] size:CGSizeMake(20, 20)];
    ballNode.position = CGPointMake(770,300);
    ballNode.zPosition = 100;
    ballNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:10];
    ballNode.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    ballNode.physicsBody.restitution = 0;
    ballNode.physicsBody.friction = 0.0;
    ballNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CategoryBall;
    ballNode.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = CategoryFloor0;
    [self addChild:ballNode];
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

    // check if ball has fallen off screen
    // if yes, put ball back in place
    if(ballNode.position.y < 0) {
        ballNode.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);
        ballNode.position = CGPointMake(770, 300);
    }
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // change the dx velocity to apply more or less force to the ball
    [ballNode.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(-7, 0)];
}
```

Comment: Yes, my question was, when a ball rolls onto the slope it should get effected by the degree of this slope so a physicaleffect onto the ball.  Image a complete flat field, but in some places there are small slopes with a given degree, which will affect the movement of the ball. As I now checked your code example. I have a question: the "trianglePath" is this responsible for the effect like a slope?

Comment: @chris922205 - The triangle slope is a clear colored SKSpriteNode which uses a CGPath as its physics body.

Comment: Ok, but how exactly is now an effect affected to the ball? that it change the behaviour of the ball?

Comment: Ok, I think we had a small missunderstanding. What I want to create is following: 
I have a flat plane, where in each corner a slope should be, that when the ball is "stucked" in the corner it should roll back to the game field.

Comment: @chris922205 - "stucked" ?

Comment: yes when the ball stops in "unreachable" corner the ball should roll back the game field, like on a slope, but I don't know how to realize this